# Design an system for redirecting pages in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I need some help in designing an system where we need to dynamically add page redirect rules for our application.

Whenever the request comes to the servlet ( all requests comes to this servlet) i have to check whether the url exists for redirect by looking at some db or from some other resource and redirect it accordingly.

The best solution to do this is through apache rewrite rules, but it requires a deployment whenever we make changes to it so we are not looking for such solution.

So we want to move an approach where we want to configure this rules inside db (which can be configured at runtime) which will be picked up by my application. To reduce the connection latency between the application and db we are planning to implement edge cache.

Could you suggest your ideas on this approach ?

Comment: Idea: start coding. There's not much to design. You need a servlet, be able to query a database table, and be able to do a redirect. All of this is pretty basic and usual stuff.

Comment: if we keep the redirect rules in the DB and access them instead of keeping them apache rewrite rules, wont that add latency to the request. I just wanted to know if there is a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Option #1

**All java solution**, no apache required, only servlet container like Tomcat. If you remember the spec, you need to define mapping in web.xml, so once your code get executed it's too late to change anything about incoming request URL, mapping has already happened.

- **Suboption a:** You don't use any MVC frameworks like Spring or Struts. Put your code into interceptor filter and issue an http redirect according to your rules. It has a drawback of additional http request i.e. increased latency
- **Suboption b:** If you do use some MVC engine, it already route all requests via some single marshaling servlet which decides about which filters and servlest to call. Extend this logic to inject your rewrite rules. This solution has best possible latency but non transferable between MVC engines.

Option #2 (which I'd probably implement first)

Have a cron job, that reads your rules from DB, forms a new .htaccess file and puts it into the appropriate folder. You don't need to restart Apache, it will read it on every request. Yes it will be a bit slower, but I bet you would not notice it anyway and dev cost is like ~1h at most.